# getting error `undefined is not a function` after mapping result of an api call inside child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, mapping

So I am calling an api and storing the result in a state called `shift` and getting the following result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "status": "created",
        "expected": {
            "end_time": "2021-10-01",
            "start_time": "2021-10-01"
        },
    },
    {
        "id": 567,
        "status": "created",
        "expected": {
            "end_time": "2021-09-30",
            "start_time": "2021-09-30"
        },
    }
]
```

Now I am mapping this `shift` state in following way:

```
{shift.map((item: any, key: any) => (
    <>
        <ShiftComponent
            id={item.id}
            StartTime={item.expected.start_time}
            EndTime={item.expected.end_time}
        />
    </>
))}
```

now taking this `id`, inside this `ShiftComponent` I am making another api call and storing it's result in state `shiftDetails`

```
const id = props.id;

const getShiftDetails = useCallback(() => {
    Apicall('shift/' + id)
        .then(async (resp) => {
            if (resp) {
                setShiftDetails(resp.data);
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Error', resp);
            }
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    getShiftDetails();
}, [getShiftDetails]);
```

api response:

```
{  
    "created_at": "2020-09-30",
    "shift_name": "nice111",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "id": "123"
}
{  
    "created_at": "2021-09-30",
    "shift_name": "nice222",
    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
    "id": "567"
}
```

At this point I am not getting any error, I am getting my response from api as well. So there is nothing wrong untill this part.

But as soon as I map my state `shiftDetails`, I am getting error `undefined is not a function`

`ShiftComponent`:

```
<View>
        {shiftDetails.map((item: any, key: any) => (
            <>
                <Text>
                    {shiftDetails.shift_name}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                    {StartTime}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                    {EndTime}
                </Text>
            </>
        ))}
</View>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, please help

Comment: Please share full and complete code. What is `shiftDetails`? Where is it declared? What is the value of `resp.data` that you are updating it to?

Comment: @DrewReese , I have added what you asked for, please have a look

Comment: Can you update your question to include [minimal, complete, and reproducible code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what each component is doing, and with what? The second API response also seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Details response is not array. Back should retur array:

```
[{  
    "created_at": "2020-09-30",
    "shift_name": "nice111",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "id": "123"
},
{  
    "created_at": "2021-09-30",
    "shift_name": "nice222",
    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
    "id": "567"
}]
```